# relative path couldn't be opened

Tags: c++, file, relative-path

In the project i am working on,  during run-time I need to open some file and read it

```
std::ifstream vSettings(".\\..\\..\\Data\\data.xml");
if (vSettings.good())
{


    //file found ,work with it

}
```

I never get true for the `good()` call above.
Manually I checked that the file indeed exists relatively to the .exe.

the path to exe is \main\proj\bin\Debug-Win32.the path to file main\proj\Data.When running in the user computer the directory will be installed relatively to the .exe

I work in debug mode and path is as it looks from the "bin" directory point of view.

Any advises?

Comment: The working directory may not be the directory in which the executable resides.

Comment: That first dot seems wrong to me.. how many directories you want to change back? if you add an extra dot like `"..\\..\\..\\Data\\data.xml"` it will go three directories back from the current path

Comment: @SamGamgee  - the path to exe is \main\proj\bin\Debug-Win32.the path to file main\proj\Data

Comment: And the absolute path to the `data.xml file? I think it should work if you use the absolute, then figure out how to use the relative

Comment: Yakov, see the comment from @SethCarnegie.  The path to the exe is irrelevant.  Yo0u need to find out the **working directory**.

Comment: Even though your exe is in \main\proj\bin\Debug-Win32 I think your IDE is settings the working directory to \main\proj

Comment: @AndréPuel If this is VS, you're correct. the default workingdir for a VC++ project is the directory where the .vcxproj file is located.

Comment: @DrewDormann - yes it works for the absolute path.but when running in the user computer the directory will be installed relatively to the .exe .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Debugging settings

[image]

and change the $(ProjectDir) to $(OutDir), and it should behave like you expect